# MATLAB plot goes outside of its box after saving as eps

Tags: matlab, plot

I have plotted the following figure, and I have saved it as eps.

[fig1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7ZA3.png)

When I convert it to PDF, I get the following:

[fig2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8CVs.png)

The blue plot is gone out of boundary although I have used ylim command. Below please see my code:

```
    h=figure(2);
set(0,'defaultAxesFontName', 'times',...
    'defaultTextFontName','times',...
    'DefaultAxesFontSize', 8, ...
    'DefaultTextFontSize', 8, ...
    'DefaultLineLineWidth',.5,...
    'DefaultLineMarkerSize', 3,...
    'DefaultTextInterpreter','latex')
h.Color='w';
h.Units = 'inches';
h.Position=[1 .5 3.61 2.71];
h.PaperPosition=[1 .5 3.61 2.71];

subplot(2,1,1)
plot(T,1000*yt,'r')
ylabel('$$y$$~(mV)','interpreter','latex')
xlim([0 49.5])
ylim([-75 75])
hold on
line([5 5],[-75 75],'linestyle','--','color','k','linewidth',1)
set(gca,'Xtick',5:10:50,'XTickLabel',5:10:50)  
set(gca,'xticklabel',[])
ylabh = get(gca,'YLabel');
 set(ylabh,'Position',get(ylabh,'Position') -[1.2 0 0])
set(gca,'xticklabel',[])

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(T,1000*ut)
ylabel('$$u$$~(mV)','interpreter','latex')
xlabel('$$t$$~(s)','interpreter','latex')
xlim([0 49.5])
ylim([-600 600])
hold on
line([5 5],[-600 600],'linestyle','--','color','k','linewidth',1)
set(gca,'Xtick',5:10:50,'XTickLabel',5:10:50)  
hold on
line([0 T(end)],[447 447],'color','k','linestyle',':','linewidth',1)
line([0 T(end)],[-447 -447],'color','k','linestyle',':','linewidth',1)
print -depsc fig_siso_bad_sat.eps
```

Comment: Do you know where the maximum and minimum values occur?  Because then I'd probably set the y-axis bounds to be those values.

Comment: @ProgrammingEnthusiast I know them. They are quite large (unbounded). I do not want to show them. I want to crop the plot at 600 (or another finite value)

Comment: Would it work to use an `if` statement?  `if MaxValue <= 600 || MinValue >= -600` and then you index those values into a new vector (need a `for` loop too)?  If you want an example of it, let me know and I'll write a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

built in export functions often do rescaling of the fugure's elements unless you fiddle with the export properties. Try using this library https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig